# Type assertion for promises with multiple return types

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I've been having trouble using type assertions with multiple promise return types. Here's a stripped down version of the code:

```js
interface SimpleResponseType {
   key1: string
};

interface SimpleResponseType2 {
   property1: string
   property2: number 
};

interface ServiceType {
   fetchResponse: () => Promise<SimpleResponseType | SimpleResponseType2> 
};

class Service implements ServiceType {
   async fetchResponse() {
      // code to fetch some api data and return some json
      // just return a pretend/sample response 
      return { key1: 'json' };
   };
};

const service = new Service();

await service.fetchResponse().then(resp => {
   // Should be typeof SimpleResponseType
   console.log(resp.key1)
})
```

TypeScript will underline the last `key1` and throw this error:

```
Property 'key1' does not exist on type 'SimpleResponseType2'.ts(2339)
```

Which makes sense, but when I attempt to assert the type more errors show up. For example asserting it like this:

```js
await service.fetchResponse().then((resp as SimpleResponseType) => {
```

It throws this err:

```
Argument of type 'SimpleResponseType' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: SimpleResponseType | SimpleResponseType2) => SimpleResponseType | SimpleResponseType2 | PromiseLike<...>'.
Type 'SimpleResponseType' provides no match for the signature '(value: SimpleResponseType | SimpleResponseType2): SimpleResponseType | SimpleResponseType2
```

The only assertion I can get working is like this:

```js
const respTyped = resp as SimpleResponseType
```

And then use `respTyped` instead of `resp`.

Maybe there's a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your code [works as is](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrALYAcA2EBKEAzlgPYhEQAqAnligN4CwAUMuwNYQ0CMAXMiJgooAOasAvgG5WrUJFiIU6bHkIlylWvQBMyZm3ZYopelDC8BQkSHGHkx09As6BIAK4YARtGSSZLHLg0PBIaNAAbsBI2oys7MgwEGAIABbqZBQQAgAUAJTIALwAfMgACiYYwJQAPCq4BMSZWnQoAD5omA0ZmtStOqX+siwIOHBEROFQUWFdeBgQ4JOokdF99Prx7OM0IAiJyWk9Wfmb9glQye5QIPrIXJbIAOQAVkTkT8jSW18B34EjTRgQSrMKFZAgCAAdymMwg+QCrEo0zWADokil0k1evlUWBUoscpcSEVSgYEghNKQ8KicKRRESmqiHjw8pI8kA) due to type inference of `Service.fetchResponse`

Comment: Interesting that it works in the playground. I run into several errors locally. My local version is a little older: "typescript": "^4.5.4"

Comment: It all comes down to `Service.fetchResponse` narrowing its return type to `SimpleResponseType` (or even further) instead of the union (if this doesn't happen by type inference you can also explicitly declare it), and the `service` that you call the method on being a `Service` and not a generic `ServiceType`.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). But you would need to have different input parameters on the function. I don't know your specific case but it seems a bit odd that there could be two different return types for the same exact API/function call.

**Edit:** You can try something like this, if you want to use the same function for multiple API routes.

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrALYAcA2EBKEAzlgPYhEQAqAnligN4BQyrA1hDQIwBcyRYKKADmTAL4BuJqEixEKdNjyES5SrXoAmZM1bIsUUvShhufAUJCi9Bo9FOa%20IAK4YARtGTipp%20mky4BMRkFNR0EADMyAC8yACCUFBwNAA8ioEqIerhmgB8UkwQLhjI%20KTOkEQ6LHplFRBcMcgARAD0cFjArYb1XM0ANDWsdZDasW0dXT2jA0Ol5ZAA6gAKcEkl4%202d3QsQmq08wAAmzeJMTAg4cERVqNAAbsBI1XPXNCAIyDAQYAgAFpk1BAABTTCB8EbEAB0kK4AEpkHxloYMMBKGkAspgkCNBB8q8iO9Pt9fgDsaFQbsIbsiDDdpoEUiUWiIBilEFVKFcXkpHpkG8Pl8fv9ARSwdT6rTISs1nAMP19LKMEQ%20AxkMcnK4PFBkGJGchkaRUej0ljOdl6BF8XyBcThWTzSDxfNJQqsEqiAB%20CEQBCkKBHFIWEQK4NWZAAH2QxW1uQRuj5ejwYGQzigOER-EEIiaYN5idYwBgyGB7vWVQAhNFYs4QEcIDBQBAjvG5gXWK1uhBcPJ%20TgM2W5VUAO7AMB-ZDjlCD5WKm7NtvttMZ2IAeTcACtfWAoUVs8RSx64VCoM3nEhgaXT49ykQAGpwHDOcFZyzCBUAbRnCvuj%20fAF0EWiXJqnbMDkFPMA0xAfRr2AW8HyfCAT27K4LwAAx4AASBgZzEdCFQAckI5AAGpkF-JC4UXAsxAVME4XzWiaOQP0KFIPAoRwUhhGBZdGJYztkAATXKZAjlIZBuMoSdwgAWiIOASRodUKGOFBxzRL5awQMB4JAKFkCoVBxNIYgQEIlMEDWFAiwg3Z1SqdDYXQ-k62QGgxMEFSwEkyDoOQdDTQ5LIwi0dCoUE1ojL%20OAwEIqpnCwSdJM85wUuQDA4A4fg02Qli2IEcS4rgJo1Q4MxkASo4YBIsQCrUFMjhKsYdFguwTEqwjKMIt1DGMBw%20AiAAWABWXUmMTFj-KgGCQAgYcDWZShL1PIggJAhNwP4H4qEwCAFkvDaIIPZqwDgBkFS4AAGa7qLAvU5kkbxzmBW1gWOrbWMa-lOiaebFruKBHgvAS%20UKpqSqaOBhzgMdfuAKESRFckVshKVdnhSaIeK87WphuGU0mJH7VFNGaTpeoGQKPlO1E9LhB%20WT6EU5Svn9RVyxS0hIptWH4eJ5GHVC4F0cppZVnWRjkE7UBKOOc5wZ%20s64GG6H%20aJzoSdJMmQTF6VJblBU1Q1ZBhtu3UBL1D6gA)

```
interface SimpleResponseType {
   key1: string
};
interface SimpleResponseType2 {
   property1: string
   property2: number 
};
type SimpleResponseType3 = Array<SimpleResponseType2>;

enum Routes {
    Route1 = "/api/route1",
    Route2 = "/api/route2",
    RouteWParam = "/api/route2/:id"
}

class Service {

    async fetchResponse(route: Routes.Route1) : Promise<SimpleResponseType>;
    async fetchResponse(route: Routes.Route2) : Promise<SimpleResponseType2>;
    async fetchResponse(route: Routes.RouteWParam, params: { id: number }) : Promise<SimpleResponseType3>;
    async fetchResponse(route: Routes, params?: Record<string, string | number>) {
        let url : string = route;
        if (params !== undefined) {
            //replace all params with the params passed
            url = Object.entries(params).reduce((previousValue: string, [param, value]) => {
                return previousValue.replace(`:${param}`, '' + value)
            }, route);
        }
        // You do lose type-safety inside this function. TS doesn't care if route is `Route1` and you try to return `SimpleResponseType2`.
        // That's up to you to make sure.
        const data = { key1: 'sdf' }
        const data2 = { property1: 'val', property2: 345 };
        
        return new Promise((res) => {
            setTimeout(() => res(data2), 100)
        })
    };
};
```

Comment: Good call! We ended up implementing it yesterday. Yeah, that example is really basic, in  actuality we're pulling from multiple endpoints. Any thoughts on writing a good reusable method to just fetch some data? Seems redundant to have a method/fetch call for each endpoint.

Comment: @Ryan updated the answer with a suggestion, with working example.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're aiming to achieve but perhaps this is what you're aiming for. Strongly typing your Service type so that you know the precise response type.

```
interface SimpleResponseType {
   key1: string
};

interface SimpleResponseType2 {
   property1: string
   property2: number 
};

interface ServiceType<T extends SimpleResponseType | SimpleResponseType2> {
   fetchResponse: () => Promise<T> 
};

class Service implements ServiceType<SimpleResponseType> {
   async fetchResponse() {
      // code to fetch some api data and return some json
      // just return a pretend/sample response 
      return { key1: 'json' };
   };
};

const service = new Service();
export {}
await service.fetchResponse().then(resp => {
   // Should be typeof SimpleResponseType
   console.log(resp.key1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return { key1 = 'json' };
```

It looks like you are doing something strange. What if you type:

```
return { key1: 'json' };
```

Comment: Good catch Roman! That is a typo and I'll fix it. However, it doesn't have much to do with solving the question.